# What are advantages of using NPM over a script include?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to understand NPM. What are advantages in using NPM over a script include?

Comment: The two are not mutually exclusive. In fact, how exactly would you ever include JavaScript in your document without a script tag?

Comment: They are two separate things. NPM is a central database of software. Like apt in Debian or yum in RedHat or Apple's App Store or Android's Marketplace. The real competitor of npm is manually googling for the script name and downloading them yourself - not include

Comment: what do you mean by script include ? can you add example ?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that by script include you mean downloading and hard importing your module in your Node script.
(i.e. `require("./mylib.js")` instead of `require("mylib")`.

NPM allows you to manage easily all the packages you need for your application (for example, easily run `npm install` to automatically download all your required packages).

Just as it stands for, NPM is a package manager. It just makes you coding easier.